# how can i get the cities income if they're incomes are greater than for example $50000?

Tags: python, mysql, input

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE '%70000%'

```
mycursor = df.cursor()

income = input("income :")
mycursor.execute("SELECT zip, city, state_name, income_household_median \
                  FROM sample\
                  WHERE income_household_median > LIKE '%"+income+"%' \
                  ORDER BY income_household_median DESC")


myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
    print(x)
```

Comment: Can you clarify? There doesn't seem to be a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not combine > with like  and that is why will go wrong and switch to replacements

```
mycursor = df.cursor()

income = input("income :")
mycursor.execute("SELECT zip, city, state_name, income_household_median \
                  FROM sample\
                  WHERE income_household_median  > %s \
                  ORDER BY income_household_median DESC",( income,))


myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
    print(x)
```

Comment: thank you, i know that but i need the codes shows up ; for example if the income greater than $50000 print all cities in that specific income

Comment: but why do you want a  `like` in the text  just write `> %S`

Comment: if LIKE is not working i can remove it, do you know any solution for that?

Comment: skip the LIKE that is only for text  let the > stay like in my changed code

Comment: thank you, worked very well

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the greater than sign before the like

Must be:

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT zip, city, state_name, income_household_median \
                  FROM sample\
                  WHERE income_household_median LIKE '%"+income+"%' \
                  ORDER BY income_household_median DESC")
```

Comment: thank you, i know that but i need the codes shows up ; for example if the income greater than $50000 print all cities in that specific income